# connecting robomongo with modulus mongodb server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I use [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) to connect to my free [modulus.io](https://modulus.io/) mongodb server? In node.js code, I can do this to connect to my database:

```
// config/database.js
module.exports = {

    'url' : 'mongodb://<user>:<pass>@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/ytub8Upa'

};
```

What's the equivalent in Robomongo? It asks for `Address` and the port number after `:`. How do I point it to my modulus database?

Answer (score 2):

In **Connection** tab:

Address: `mongo.onmodulus.net`.

Port: `27017`

In **Authentication** tab:

Check "Perform authentication", and specify username and password.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Dmitry's answer above, you also need to specify a database nmae in the **Authentication** tab: using your example code, that would be `ytub8Upa`.

More info:

- http://scotch.io/quick-tips/mongodb/connecting-to-mongodb-using-robomongo
- http://blog.modulus.io/robomongo-modulus-mongodb